# Getting an Error : "The expression is involved in a cycle" while running Azure Bicep code

Tags: json, azure-bicep

[image]

I decompiled json file to bicep file using VS Code. After the decompilation, I am getting the following error:

The expression is involved in a cycle ("virtualNetworks_VNET_DEV_name_SNET_APPDEV01" -> "virtualNetworks_VNET_DEV_name_resource").bicep(BCP080)

Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont need to specify the virtual network id here  so just remove the property

Comment: Can you share the Json code which you attached in the snap here. @Sandeep Taksande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/565) for the similar error *"Expression involved in a cycle"* while decompiling from `JSON` to `Bicep`.

This error comes when a bicep compiler finds that a parameter or resource is pointing out itself.

To correct it, remove the reference to a resource that is referring itself, as there is no need to do so.

***Two ways to remove the error:***

1. Remove the reference as I detailed above and thanks @Thomas for suggesting it.
2. Alternatively as a workaround, use [`resourceId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#resourceid) to reference the corresponding symbolic resource and access the resource Id property which is detailed in the given MS Doc.

Here I tried to decompile a sample template into `Bicep` from `Json`. The `resourcedId` function is used in the `JSON` code to access the `Id`, as showed.

After decompilation, it was changed to `nsg.id` and no error was thrown. It fails to operate properly in every case, and you had the same problem. That is why I recommended you use one of the ways I described above.

[image]

[image]